# Fortify SCA CommandLine Invocation Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fortify

Hi the following exception when trying to scan my Solution using Fority..

[image]

I have ildasm in Windows/System32 folder which is the default place. And I am able to open the ildasm.exe from the command prompt. Please let me know, wat I am missing.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, with fortify 4.0 of 64bit.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to locate the ildasm.exe tool can be solved as suggested by greencrizz but can also be specified on the command line if needed with: 
-Dcom.fortify.sca.IldasmPath=C:\path\to\ildasm.exe

The "No rules files found" means exactly that, there the rules have not been downloaded. These can either be downloaded with fortifyupdate from the command line, within options of an IDE plugin/AWB or manually via the Fortify Support Portal. 
Also note if you have access to the Fortify Support Portal, there is a Knowledge Base section which includes solutions to problems such as this.

Answer (score 0):

did you modify the key com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath in your \Core\config\fortify-sca.properties? Put the path to your ildasm.exe on the right hand side.

com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath=C:\PATH\TO\ildasm.exe

Note that you need to escape the backslashes. (\\)

Hope that helps